# JQuery form tooltip

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In a big form, I want to display additional information on each form field *when they are active*, something like this:

[image]

So each form field has an associated tip text, and this tip text is displayed on focus.

Something linke this in html/javascript:

```
<input type="text" id="VIN" name="VIN" class="tooltipped">

<label for="VIN" class="formfieldtooltip">A vehicle Iden... </label>

<input type="text" id="Brand" name="Brand" class="tooltipped">

<label for="Brand" class="formfieldtooltip">In Danish "brand" means "fire"</label>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($) {

        $(".tooltipped").FormFieldToolTipBinder();

    });

</script>
```

That runs through all form fields with the class "tooltipped" and displays the associated label on focus.

Does something like that exist already, or do I have to write it myself?

And yes, I have googled - and found a lot of plugins to make the actual tooltips, but nothing that wires them up with formfields automagically like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you may be stuck embedding tooltip content in the `label` elements - but if you're free to move the content into the `alt` attribute of your `input` elements, [you can do what you want with qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/), like this:

```
<input type="text" id="VIN" class="tooltipped" alt="A vehicle iden...">
```

and

```
// content: false tells qtip to use the selected elements' alt text
$('.tooltipped').qtip({
    content: false,
    show: { when: { event: 'focus' } }
});
```

Comment: Actually I was not stuck with that, so this works perfectly. I just added some handling for the blur event, so the tips go away again, and then I was done.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's quite easy to write yourself. Here's something to get you started:

```
var tooltip = function (formElementId) {
    var form = $('#' + formElementId),
        toolTipClass = 'tooltip',
        input = form.find('input.'+ tooltip);

    input.each(function (index, elem) {
        $(elem).focus(function () {
            $(this).parent().append('<div id="tooltip"></div>');
        })

        $(elem).blur(function () {
            $('#tooltip').remove();
        })
    });
}
```