# html text box displaying hint when in focus

Tags: html, css

How do I create a text box that displays hint on the right when in focus?

Example : http://www.airbnb.com/rooms/new
(click on the address text box)

Comment: If jQuery is fine for you I think this was once already answered over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874067/jquery-form-tooltip

Answer (score 4):

It's also possible without javascript.

```
<input type="text" value="Focus me to see a hint!" style="width: 200px; height: 30px;"/>
<div>Congratulations, you found me !</div>
```

---

```
.input + div {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    left: 200px;
}

.input:focus + div {
        display: block;
}
```

Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its is simple with placeholder

```
<input type="text" placeholder = "your gray text" />
```